# Implement non-generic interface containing generic method

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface, which contain generic method signature:

```
interface IFetcher {
  fetch<T>(): T;
}
```

I want to mock it in unit tests, so I tried:

```
const mockFetch: IFetcher = {
  fetch: (): T => {
    return {} as T;
  }
}
```

but I am getting the following error:

> Cannot find name 'T'.

Other variants I tried:

```
const mockFetch: IFetcher = {
  fetch: <T>(): T  => {
    return {} as T;
  }
}
```

which leads to

> Cannot find name 'React'.

and

```
const mockFetch: IFetcher = {
  fetch<T>: (): T => {
    return {} as T;
  }
}
```

which leads to

> Type '() => () => any' is not assignable to type '() => T'.
> Type '() => any' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '() => any'.

This works:

```
const mockFetch: IFetcher = {
  fetch: (): any => {
    return {};
  }
}
```

but I don't want to use `any`.

And this also works, but introduces another type:

```
interface A {
}

const mockFetch: IFetcher = {
  fetch:<A extends unknown>(): A => {
    return {} as A;
  }
}
```

What is the proper way to implement this interface, preserving type safety as much as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tsx files, `<T>` will be interpreted as the start of a JSX tag. You can add a `,` which will convince typescript this is a type parameter list not a JSX tag (trailing commas are allowed in type parameter lists)

```
const mockFetch: IFetcher = {
  fetch: <T,>(): T  => {
    return {} as T;
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDEJgQC2sgbwChlkYtcAeAFQD4AKASgC5lqBuIgXyKIQHsQAZzDIAtvwQBrTNhysMFPFGQBeQiTJLWNADQMWbUqtobSpKFgCuUEIS7I4Qtp1I8uQA)